# VHDL found '0' definition of operator "+" cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "+"

Tags: vhdl

I have the problem that this line `B1 <= (-c1 * (A3 + A1) + A3 + A2 - A1);` keeps showing up as an error. I am aware that this problem already exists on stackoverflow, but none of the solutions have helped me. I've already created the project from scratch, which didn't help either. I don't know what to do next and I hope someone can help me here.

thanks in advance

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_arith.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_signed.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_unsigned.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;



entity ParallelAdaptor is
    Port ( A1 : in STD_LOGIC;
           A2 : in STD_LOGIC;
           A3 : in STD_LOGIC;
           c1 : in STD_LOGIC;
           B1 : out STD_LOGIC;
           B2 : out STD_LOGIC;
           B3 : out STD_LOGIC);
end ParallelAdaptor;

architecture Behavioral of ParallelAdaptor is

begin

    B1 <= (-c1 * (A3 + A1) + A3 + A2 - A1);


end Behavioral;
```

Comment: The sign operator and arithmetic operators for addition, subtraction and multiplication all have conventional mathematical meaning in VHDL (IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2.5 Adding operators, 9.2.6 Sign operators, 9.2.7 Multiplying operator). Mathematics deals with *numbers* (arithmetical values). Logical operators deal with binary values, the domain of Boolean algebra. It's clear none of the mathematical packages in use clauses supply overloads for std_logic. It's not clear what you intend without providing inputs and expected outputs. Is this intended to be Boolean algebra or mathematical numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think STD_LOGIC is a single bit (my vhdl experiences are ~20 years ago) and you can't do these kind of operations on it.
So you need at least an output that can hold the result...
And output B2 and B3 is not used...

I suggest you should try something from here https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/tutorials/tutorial-introduction-to-vhdl-for-beginners.html

Comment: This answer doesn't clarify the question. Relying on external links for the questions author to discover an answer to the unclear question as is can't enlighten future readers using Stackoverflow as a search resource.